# I'm trying to resize a forward list without using the resize() method

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, reverse

I want to try reversing a forward_list (without the reverse() method) but I'm not sure how to get rid of the last element after the erase_after() method without using resize().

```
#include<forward_list>  

template<typename vt>
class reverse_forward_list{
public:
    static void reverse(std::forward_list<vt>& list){
        
        typename std::forward_list<vt>::iterator iter = list.begin();
        int x = 0;
        for(vt& i :list){
            list.emplace_front(i);
            
            x++;
        }
        list.erase_after(iter,list.end());
        
        //list.resize(x);
    }
};
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use [`list.before_begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/before_begin) instead to also erase the previous first element.

Also, this can be implemented more efficiently by [splicing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/splice_after) each node to the front of the list (which is probably how `reverse` works internally, and you won't have to allocate new nodes/construct new values)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there should be a VERY good reason for manipulating a list while traversing it... It's a disaster waiting to happen.

Instead, consider using a temporary list, something like that:

```
template<typename vt>
static void reverse(std::forward_list<vt>& list) {
  std::forward_list<vt> newlist;
  while (!list.empty()) {
    newlist.push_front(list.front());
    list.pop_front();
  }
  list = newlist;
}
```